# prove that $(k+1)^a - 1$ is divisible by k

Tags: induction

prove that $(k+1)^a - 1$ is divisible by k

Base case: n = 0;

$(k+1)^0$ -1 = k which is divisible by k

IH: $(b+1)^a - 1$ is divisible by b

for a + 1

$(b+1)^{a+1}$ -1
= $(b+1)(b+1)^{a} -1 $

Comment: Last step; $(b+1)(b+1)^{a} -1=b(b+1)^a+(b+1)^a-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have above, I assume that $k$, $a$, and $b$ are all natural numbers.

Then you can say (IH): $$(b+1)^{a}-1=bm$$ where $m$ is also a real number. Now for $a+1$:
$$(b+1)^{a+1}-1$$
$$\Rightarrow (b+1)(b+1)^{a}-1$$
$$\Rightarrow b(b+1)^{a}+(b+1)^{a}-1$$
Now you can make the substitution for the (IH)
$$\Rightarrow b(b+1)^{a}+bm$$
$$\Rightarrow b((b+1)^{a}+m)$$
Hence, since $(b+1)^{a}+m)$ is a natural number (call it $n$), you can write this final proof as $bn$, which is obviously divisible by $b$.